# how to know the vendor prefix of a selector, property, or value?

Tags: css, vendor-prefix

When I want to vendor prefix something like @media e.g. I usually use a search engine like google. E.g. [this link](https://gist.github.com/afabbro/3492086) shows a special way to prefix a min-device-pixel-ratio using -moz-; it's like

> min--moz-device-pixel-ratio

instead of

> -moz-min-device-pixel-ratio

As far as I know, CanIUse tells whether a browser supports a property or not, but it doesn't tell how to prefix it, same as for [this link](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/which-vendor-prefixes-are-needed/). Correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm sort of newbie, so I don't think Autoprefixer is a good choice.

Comment: It is likely due to a mistake: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

Comment: Use [**Mozilla Developer Network**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/)